# What kind of math is used in c++ Hello world program?

Tags: c++, math

I was recently asked this question at an interview what is the math used in a simple cpp or c hello world program ?
Was it a trick question or is any math really being used ?

Comment: That's a terrible interview question.

Comment: Mostly binary math of calculating memory addresses.

Comment: @Gill Probably depends on what they expect as an answer.

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer here. They just want to hear you reason about the question.

Comment: Don't worry: if they do not take you because of such questions, they will be soon out of business anyway...  By the way, the best answer is integer maths  (return value, offset and pointers increments for the stream and the string, comparison of char to special values, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

A simple hello world program does not use much arithmetic at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The examiner might expect this answer:

- Such programs usually do not use floating point arithmetic, only integer arithmetic.

Note that C programs that use floating point arithmetic and functions should be linked with the math library, which may require an explicit `-lm` link option on unix systems.

Such a question is really inane, but in an oral interview, it is a chance to tell the interviewer what you know about integer and floating point arithmetic, and also multi-precision and complex stuff.